# How to define password to access to the site?

Tags: .net, asp.net, silverlight, password-protection

I never wrote asp.net web site.

I wrote some silverlight web application and i using the default asp.net hosting to run my silverlight application.

I want to define some password that will limited the ability to use my silverlight application. 
I want to do it by adding the asp.net site a 'login' possibility by password.

Someone can help me and tell me how to do it ? is there some simple code example ?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have a look at this link http://www.asp.net/web-forms/overview/older-versions-security/introduction/security-basics-and-asp-net-support-cs

and [ASP.NET 2.0 Membership, Roles, Forms Authentication, and Security Resources](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2006/02/24/ASP.NET-2.0-Membership_2C00_-Roles_2C00_-Forms-Authentication_2C00_-and-Security-Resources-.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Introduce a `Login page` before your `main page`, ask for password in your `login page`, if user enters password successfully, grant him access, else don't.